# How Do I Align Icons?

Tags: css, font-awesome

[Here's a screenshot of how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vBTe.png) How do I align these icons to the h2? I want them on the left of those h2, and I would also like to increase their size. Of course, if possible, without destroying the layout I've built.
I tried using float right but I am really struggling in having them looking properly on the left of my H2.
 Please help!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

#main-content {
  background-color: #000000;
  background-image: linear-gradient(147deg, #000000 0%, #04619f 74%);
  color: white;
  padding: 2%;
}

#header-content h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#header-content p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#content-icons {
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: inline;
}

#content-icons i {
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="row align-items-center" id="main-content">
      <div class="col fade-in" id="header-content">
        <h1>UK Bridging Loans</h1>
        <p>Your Bridging Finance Partner</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col float-right" id="content-icons">
        <ul class="fa-ul">
          <li>
            <span class="fa-li"><i class="far fa-building"></i></span>
            <h2>Commercial Bridging Loans</h2>
            <p>
              Find out more about our commercial bridging loans to fund your
              project here.
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-store-alt"></i></span>
            <h2>Secured Bridging Loans</h2>
            <p>
              Secured bridging loans are the most popular form, securing the
              loan against an existing property brings better interest rates and
              more interest from lenders. Find out more here.
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-warehouse"></i></span>
            <h2>Unsecured Bridging Loans</h2>
            <p>
              Unsecured bridging loans are harder to get hold of as banks
              normally insist on securing your loan against a property/asset of
              some kind. However, we are approved to offer this option to
              customers. Find out more here.
            </p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you share a screen shot . because i put this in fiddle and the icons are on the left, 
and i  think in first icon, far is wrong, its fas or fa.

Comment: added a screenshot at the beginning!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a flex box. Wrap everything that you want to display in a single line and assign display property to flex.